# import javascript file in my angular 2 projet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

i"m working in angular projet and i want to add two javascript file in my project ; so i just include those js file in my assets and call them in my angular cli script part . i can see that those file are called correcty .

but i have this problems :
[image]

my html code is :

```
<div   class=" demo-1">
   <div class="content">
     <div id="large-header" class="large-header">
       <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
       <h1 class="main-title">ALTEN <span class="thin">GAV²</span></h1>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div><!-- /container -->
```

and my js code is :

```
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};
        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');

      canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
```

when i try to log the largeHeader viariable in my js it return null .
this code work correctly . but including it in angular cli make problems .
is that a problem of webpack ? 
thank you in advance

Comment: Kept in angular-cli.json ???

Answer (score 1):

It's important to say what build tool you are using. If it's Webpack based (ie. Angular CLI) then you can reference a JavaScript file (or any other type) with one of the following:

```
import * as test from './test.js';
// or
require('./test.js');
```

However, your error message indicates that your JavaScript is running, but it's failing on these lines:

```
largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
```

It's not finding an element on your page with ID `large-header`, so the call to `.style` fails. I suspect that, because you are importing the file from the top level HTML page, the JavaScript code is running before the template has a chance to render, so the `large-header` element is not created at that point.

To diagnose further, you could use the Sources tab of the Chrome Dev Tools to set a breakpoint on the line in question, then inspect the Elements tab to see if the expected `div` is actually present at this point.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but throwing in arbitrary bits of JavaScript that are not part of the "Angular world" might not be the best way to approach an Angular app. In the long term, perhaps it would be better to refactor this code into a Component or a Directive.